# Multiplication law in a division algebra of dimension 9 over a non-archimedean local field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-fields, brauer-groups, division-algebras

Let $k$ be a non-archimedean local field, for example, a $p$-adic field (a finite extension of the filed ${\Bbb Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers).
It is well known that there is a canonical isomorphism
$${\rm inv}\colon {\rm Br}\,k\overset\sim\longrightarrow{\Bbb Q}/{\Bbb Z}.$$
Let  $D$ denote the division algebra of dimension 9 over $k$ with invariant $\frac13$.

> **Question.** How can one explicitly describe the multiplication law in $D$ ?

**Motivation.** From the multiplication law in $D$, I can obtain the commutation law in the 8-dimensional  Lie algebra ${\frak g}={\frak sl}(1,D)$.
From $\frak g$, I can obtain an explicit trilinear alternating form on the 8-dimensional space $\frak g$:
$$(x,y,z)\mapsto ([x,y],z)\quad\text{for }\,x,y,z\in{\frak g},$$
where $(\,,\,)$ denotes the Killing form.
This is a $k$-form of a generic alternating trilinear form on $k^8$.

Comment: If $K/k$ is the unramified extension of degree 3, and $\pi$ a uniformiser, then $D$ is isomorphic to the cyclic algebra $(K/k,\pi)$.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MartinBright: Yes! Many thanks! Could you please give a reference?

Comment: @MartinBright: What about the multiplication law in a division algebra of dimension 9 with given local invariants over a *global* field $k$ ?

Comment: Over a global field any division algebra is cyclic; this is one of the main theorems of class field theory (See Theorem 1.5.36 of Poonen - Rational Points over Varieties). The proof looks constructive so this may help.

Comment: @DanielLoughran: Thank you! I will try to ask a new question about division algebras over global fields.

Comment: You could also look at standard references on CSAs, e.g., see https://mathoverflow.net/a/198511/6518 for some.